# Libgdx Dispose Sprite Batch Error

Tags: libgdx

I wants to dispose a batch in my game screen. However, after i dispose, the second time i enter my game screen, error occurs which only shows the following:

```
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x00000000779ae303, pid=4816, tid=5000
#
# JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (8.0_73-b02) (build 1.8.0_73-b02)
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (25.73-b02 mixed mode windows-amd64 compressed oops)
# Problematic frame:
# C  [ntdll.dll+0x4e303]
```

My coding flow goes like this

new Main Menu screen  ->>
Game Screen (screen created by (Game)Gdx.app.getApplicationListener()).setScreen(new GameScreen(mainScreenReference),new Sprite Batch created, a reference of Main Menu Screen is passed to Game screen)->>
(After game over, in the Game Screen hide method, batch is disposed)->>
back to Main Menu Screen ->> (play again by entering into new Game Screen) ->>
   ERROR

This isn't due to duplicated dispose. Everything works well if sprite batch in game screen is not disposed. Anyone please help.

Comment: It's looks like game textures is disposed when leaving game screen

Comment: Yes. I disposed everything include texture and stage because i will create a new game screen each time i enter a new game. Is my practice correct?

Comment: You need to reload every texture if you dispose it. My game uses lightweight textures and I don't worry about texture reloading. They are loaded once and stored in memory during all game lifecycle

Comment: Sorry, i dont understand what do you means by reload the texture. I will always create a new texture if i enter the game screen, which will be disposed after i'm leaving it. Can you explain it in more details?